# Informatica PowerCenter Designer: Skip 1st column from flat file

Tags: csv, informatica, informatica-powercenter, flat-file

I have a flat file in CSV format. In that, I have 5 different columns. The 1st-row is the header. I want to Skip 1st column while importing the flat file as a source from Informatica PowerCenter Designer and only read data from rest of the 4 columns. How do I achieve this?

Note: I know, I can just import 1st column and don't map it and remove that port from Source Qualifier Transformation. Also, I don't want to remove the 1st column from my CSV flat file.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm gonna hazard a guess that you meant to say that your first column has headers (not first row as mentioned above). In that case this makes a little bit of sense but really what you should do is transpose your data with a script such as in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731502/transposing-csv-data-in-perl before importing the resulting csv and then you just configure your source to skip first row when you define it. This way your port datatypes will also be meaningful

Comment: Thanks, @DanielMachet. If I could transpose the source table before getting it to mapping then, I would prefer to remove 1st column itself before importing csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're asking (and no meaningful reason to do it either that I can discern). Now if its rows you want to skip then thats another matter