# Perl script to print all the column from a csv file into rows in a new file

Tags: csv, perl

my .csv file looks like:

```
sim_time,a,b,c,d
0,0,0,0,0
12,0,1,1,0
115,1,1,1,1
200,0,0,1,0
```

I have multiple csv file in which no of rows and column are different .

The output should look like :

```
sim_time 0 12 115 200
a 0 0 1 0
b 0 1 1 0
c 0 1 1 1
d 0 0 1 0
```

The code i am trying to use is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $file = "report_69.csv";
my $column_separator = ',';
open (my $INFILE, "<" , "$file");
open(my $FILE,">","report_69.txt") or die "$!";
while (<$INFILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @c = split(',', $_);
    my $d = @c;
    print $d;
    my @columns = split(/$column_separator/);

    for( $a = 0; $a < $d; $a = $a + 1 ) {
        push ("@x_{$a}", $columns[$a] );    # the problem (1) 
    }
}
```

The problem (1) arise while defining the array as it is not a valid way to define the array. Is there any other way to do the same.

Now I am facing issue while content of the each column into an array because I can define the multiple array as per need .

Comment: Are you open to one-liner ?

Comment: yes .. if that one liner can also be included in a script.

Comment: Explain what are you trying to achieve whit the loop in English. `$column` is not defined and `@x_{$a}` is a syntax error

Comment: i have corrected the code about @column . and about 'for loop' i am using it so that depending on the no of column in the input file , different arrays are defined and the content of column is saved into the array , so that i can use it to as per i need. .........

Comment: in short i just want to print the column of the file as the rows in a new file .

Comment: Create an array of arrays with the 1st element of the array being the column name. I'd usually use a hash here, but this example is a bit awkward to me. You know how big the sub-array needs to be from the number of columns.

Comment: Could you please help me with the code to do the same .?

Comment: Please clarify: the fourth row (`115,1,1,1`) has only four columns, but the output is five-by-five -- and it appears the a `1` is added?   Is that correct or is the missing field a typo?  (If correct, then how does one decide to add a `1` for a missing field?)

Comment: yes... you are right it is a typo ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transposing CSV data in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731502/transposing-csv-data-in-perl)

Answer (score 3):

The data in the CSV file need be transposed, judged by the shown desired output

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });

my @data;
open my $fh, $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";    
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) { 
    push @data, $row;
}
close $fh;

# Transpose data
my @res;
foreach my $row (@data) {
    foreach my $col_n (0 .. $#$row) {
        push @{ $res[$col_n] }, $row->[$col_n];
    }
}

# Print results
for my $row (@res) {
    say "@$row";
}
```

The syntax `$#$name` stands for the last index in an array reference of that `name`.

While the shown data is easily parsed by hand<sup>†</sup> it is always better to entrust the job to a library for CSV and I use the excellent [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/ISHIGAKI/Text-CSV-1.95/view/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to read and parse the CSV file.

The resulting (transposed) data is printed to `STDOUT` and so can be redirected to a file.  Or change the last part to print directly to a file.

---

<sup>†</sup>   Even as just

```
my @data = map { chomp; [ split /\s*,\s*/ ] } <>;
```

for a file which name is given on the command line (so found in `@ARGV` and thus read line by line by `<>`).   However, as soon as there is *anything* more interesting in the file -- spaces, newlines, quotes, ... -- we *really* want a library.  So just use a library.

Answer (score 1):

My simplistic answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;

my $file = "data.txt";
my $column_separator = ',';
open (my $INFILE, "<" , "$file");

my @rows = ();

my $row=0;
while (<$INFILE>) {

  chomp;
  next if (/^$/);

  my @cols = split(",");

  for(my $c = 0; $c < scalar @cols; $c++) {
    $rows[$c][$row] = "" . $cols[$c];
  }

  $row++;
}

for my $row(@rows) {
  print join(",", @{$row}), "\n";
}
```

I'm no perl expert, but this seems to tick the box (file handling excepted).

Comment: `$column_separator` is never used

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yeah, it's a trivial point, but a valid one. Theres a couple of bits I would tidy up if it were a production bit of code, but it was a quick hack this morning.