# Transposing an array of elements

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am trying to transpose an array.

I tried the following code...

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<',"op.txt" || die "$!";
open my $wh , '>',"pwl.txt" || die "$!"; 
select ($wh);
while (my $line = <$fh>) { 
  my @rows = $line;
  my @transposed;
  for my $row (@rows) {
    for my $column (0 .. $#{$row}) {
      push(@{$transposed[$column]}, $row->[$column]);
    }
  }
  for my $new_row (@transposed) {
    for my $new_col (@{$new_row}) {
      print $new_col, " ";
    }
    print "\n"; 
  }
}
```

**********INPUT FILE******

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

********** EXPECTED OUTPUT FILE *******

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

******** GENERATED OUTPUT FILE *******

Currently couldn't able print anything. script shows the error
"can't use string ("1 4 7") as an array ref while "strict refs" in use

Reference:
used the following reference...
[Transpose in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249508/transpose-in-perl)
however in this reference example, array input lines are declared manually where as i am trying to process a array which is in a text file

could anybody help me where i did mistake?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You *did* have to split input line as @dland suggested. But, there were a few other issues.

Here's the corrected code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<',"op.txt" || die "$!";
open my $wh , '>',"pwl.txt" || die "$!";

my @rows;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  my @line = split(" ",$line);
  push(@rows,\@line);
}
close($fh);

my @transposed;
for my $row (@rows) {
  push(@transposed,[]);
}

my $rowidx = -1;
for my $rowptr (@rows) {
  ++$rowidx;
  my $colidx = -1;
  for my $rowval (@$rowptr) {
    ++$colidx;
    ###printf("R=%d C=%d\n",$rowidx,$colidx);
    my $colptr = $transposed[$colidx];
    $colptr->[$rowidx] = $rowval;
  }
}

for my $new_row (@transposed) {
  for my $new_col (@$new_row) {
    print $wh $new_col, " ";
  }
  print $wh "\n";
}

close($wh);
```

*Note:* It's slightly harder to transpose a non-square matrix. The above code may need to be extended a bit for that.

Comment: There's no need for the `|| die "$!"` with `use autodie` in place

Comment: @Borodin The `die` is OP's code, not mine--I was mostly concerned with fixing the algorithm. But, in my own code base [of 250,000 lines], I couldn't use `autodie`. I have wrappers for many std fncs that handle errors automatically (e.g. default for `open` is to terminate [with optional stack traceback] _unless_ told to return `undef`). The wrappers also do tracing. And, I have special handling for `die`. IMO, handling error returns is a better model than throwing exceptions for mundane things like "file not found"

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to shove a scalar into an array:

```
my @row = $line;
```

I think what you really want is to split on spaces:

```
my @row = split / /, $line;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way of doing this. It assumes all the rows are of the same length, and that all the lines in the file contain data -- i.e. there are no blank lines

The name of the input file is expected as a parameter on the command line, and the output is sent to STDOUT so it can be redirected on the command line. For instance

```
perl transpose.pl op.txt > pwl.txt
```

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @matrix = map [ split ], <>;

print "@$_\n" for @matrix;
print "\n";

my @transpose;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#{ $matrix[0] } ) {
    $transpose[$i] = [ map { $_->[$i] } @matrix ]
}

print "@$_\n" for @transpose;
print "\n";
```

#### output

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `my @row =map [ split], $line` to my initial code is helping to print the data to pwl.txt.

however its not printing side by side.. instead it is printing to new line.
I guess because of this Mr.Borodin didn't include matrix in side while loop!

---

```
1
2
3

4
5
6

7
8
9
```