# Transpose select lines in a CSV via Perl

Tags: perl, csv, transpose

I know there are already threads about this already ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731502/transposing-csv-data-in-perl) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249508/transpose-in-perl)) but I can't seem to edit [This script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731502/transposing-csv-data-in-perl) to only return certain rows in a `CSV`. I will point out that I am relatively new to `Perl` and I am/have read the `Perl` docs for I/O but I can't seem to see what is wrong with my script.

My script currently looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @rows = ();
my @pivot = ();

open (FILE, "EDCNDC-Daily-Volume-Forecast_Ops Forecast by Shift.csv") or die $!; #Opens File or returns error thrown ($!) 

while (<FILE>) {
    if ($. < 4 ) {print ""}
    elsif ($. > 8) {print ""}
    elsif ($_ =~ /^\,\,\,\,/) {print substr($_,4)}
    else {
            chomp;
            push @rows, [split /,/];
         }
}

for my $row (@rows) {
    for my $column (0 .. $#{$row}) {
    push(@{$pivot[$column]}, $row->[$column]);
    }
}

for my $newrow (@pivot) {
    for my $newcol (@{$newrow}) {
    print $newcol,",";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close FILE or die $!;
```

This returns the following:

```
Site Activity,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,03:00 - 09:00 - Level 0 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,03:00 - 09:00 - Level 1 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.5 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,0,0,0,0,0,MI Re
port Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,0,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,Bank Hol,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.6 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.7 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0
Promotional Activity,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Sparks Preview to Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale & Cyber,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,England vs Slovakia,Sale,Sale,Sa
le,Sale,Sale,Sale,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,0,0,0,0,0,Sparks Preview to Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,England vs Malta,0,0,0,0,0,0,England vs Malta,0,0,England vs Scotland,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,H
ome Event,Home Event,0,Cyber,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F & Beauty Advent Calendar Launch (TBC),F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,0,0,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,0,0,Xmas Countdown,Xmas
 Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,0,0,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,0,0,0,0,0,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Cyber,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Mothers Day    England vs Lithuania,0,0,0,0,0,0
Fiscal week,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,
30,30,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,
45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52
Week,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,4
4,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
Date,31/7/16,1/8/16,2/8/16,3/8/16,4/8/16,5/8/16,6/8/16,7/8/16,8/8/16,9/8/16,10/8/16,11/8/16,12/8/16,13/8/16,14/8/16,15/8/16,16/8/16,17/8/16,18/8/16,19/8/16,20/8/16,21/8/16,22/8/16,23/8/16,24/8/16,25/8/16,26/8/16,27/8/16,28/8/16,29/8/16,30/8/16,31/8/16,1/9/16,2/9/16,3/9/16,4/9/16,5/9/16,6/9/16,7/9/16
,8/9/16,9/9/16,10/9/16,11/9/16,12/9/16,13/9/16,14/9/16,15/9/16,16/9/16,17/9/16,18/9/16,19/9/16,20/9/16,21/9/16,22/9/16,23/9/16,24/9/16,25/9/16,26/9/16,27/9/16,28/9/16,29/9/16,30/9/16,1/10/16,2/10/16,3/10/16,4/10/16,5/10/16,6/10/16,7/10/16,8/10/16,2/10/16,3/10/16,4/10/16,5/10/16,6/10/16,7/10/16,8/10/
16,09/10/2016,10/10/2016,11/10/2016,12/10/2016,13/10/2016,14/10/2016,15/10/2016,16/10/2016,17/10/2016,18/10/2016,19/10/2016,20/10/2016,21/10/2016,22/10/2016,23/10/2016,24/10/2016,25/10/2016,26/10/2016,27/10/2016,28/10/2016,29/10/2016,30/10/2016,31/10/2016,01/11/2016,02/11/2016,03/11/2016,04/11/2016,
05/11/2016,06/11/2016,07/11/2016,08/11/2016,09/11/2016,10/11/2016,11/11/2016,12/11/2016,13/11/2016,14/11/2016,15/11/2016,16/11/2016,17/11/2016,18/11/2016,19/11/2016,20/11/2016,21/11/2016,22/11/2016,23/11/2016,24/11/2016,25/11/2016,26/11/2016,27/11/2016,28/11/2016,29/11/2016,30/11/2016,01/12/2016,02/
12/2016,03/12/2016,04/12/2016,05/12/2016,06/12/2016,07/12/2016,08/12/2016,09/12/2016,10/12/2016,11/12/2016,12/12/2016,13/12/2016,14/12/2016,15/12/2016,16/12/2016,17/12/2016,18/12/2016,19/12/2016,20/12/2016,21/12/2016,22/12/2016,23/12/2016,24/12/2016,25/12/2016,26/12/2016,27/12/2016,28/12/2016,29/12/
2016,30/12/2016,31/12/2016,01/01/2017,02/01/2017,03/01/2017,04/01/2017,05/01/2017,06/01/2017,07/01/2017,08/01/2017,09/01/2017,10/01/2017,11/01/2017,12/01/2017,13/01/2017,14/01/2017,15/01/2017,16/01/2017,17/01/2017,18/01/2017,19/01/2017,20/01/2017,21/01/2017,22/01/2017,23/01/2017,24/01/2017,25/01/201
7,26/01/2017,27/01/2017,28/01/2017,29/01/2017,30/01/2017,31/01/2017,01/02/2017,02/02/2017,03/02/2017,04/02/2017,05/02/2017,06/02/2017,07/02/2017,08/02/2017,09/02/2017,10/02/2017,11/02/2017,12/02/2017,13/02/2017,14/02/2017,15/02/2017,16/02/2017,17/02/2017,18/02/2017,19/02/2017,20/02/2017,21/02/2017,2
2/02/2017,23/02/2017,24/02/2017,25/02/2017,26/02/2017,27/02/2017,28/02/2017,01/03/2017,02/03/2017,03/03/2017,04/03/2017,05/03/2017,06/03/2017,07/03/2017,08/03/2017,09/03/2017,10/03/2017,11/03/2017,12/03/2017,13/03/2017,14/03/2017,15/03/2017,16/03/2017,17/03/2017,18/03/2017,19/03/2017,20/03/2017,21/0
3/2017,22/03/2017,23/03/2017,24/03/2017,25/03/2017,26/03/2017,27/03/2017,28/03/2017,29/03/2017,30/03/2017,31/03/2017,01/04/2017
```

If I change the script to the following :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @rows = ();
my @pivot = ();

open (FILE, "EDCNDC-Daily-Volume-Forecast_Ops Forecast by Shift.csv") or die $!; #Opens File or returns error thrown ($!) 

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    push @rows, [split /,/];
}

for my $row (@rows) {
    for my $column (0 .. $#{$row}) {
    push(@{$pivot[$column]}, $row->[$column]);
    }
}

for my $newrow (@pivot) {
    for my $newcol (@{$newrow}) {
    print $newcol,",";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close FILE or die $!;
```

It returns the desired output except for the entire input `CSV`

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

The desired output for this script should be something like the following:

```
Site Activity, Promotional Activity, Fiscal week, Week, Date
MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30, 0, 18, 31, 31/07/2016
03:00 - 09:00 - Level 0 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop, 0, 18, 31, 01/08/2016
03:00 - 09:00 - Level 1 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop, 0, 18, 31, 02/08/2016
0, 0, 18, 31, 03/08/2016
0, 0, 18, 31, 04/08/2016
```

## EDIT 2

Input file without stripping it down:

```
EDCNDC  -Daily Volume Forecast,,,,,Issued,28th July,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
w/c 31st August,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,Site Activity,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,03:00 - 09:00 - Level 0 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,03:00 - 09:00 - Level 1 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.5 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,0,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,0,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,Bank Hol,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.6 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.7 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,,,,Promotional Activity,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Sparks Preview to Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale & Cyber,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,England vs Slovakia,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,0,0,0,0,0,Sparks Preview to Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,England vs Malta,0,0,0,0,0,0,England vs Malta,0,0,England vs Scotland,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,0,Cyber,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F & Beauty Advent Calendar Launch (TBC),F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,0,0,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,0,0,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,0,0,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,0,0,0,0,0,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Cyber,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Mothers Day    England vs Lithuania,0,0,0,0,0,0
,,,,Fiscal week,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52
,,,,Week,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
,,,,Date,31/7/16,1/8/16,2/8/16,3/8/16,4/8/16,5/8/16,6/8/16,7/8/16,8/8/16,9/8/16,10/8/16,11/8/16,12/8/16,13/8/16,14/8/16,15/8/16,16/8/16,17/8/16,18/8/16,19/8/16,20/8/16,21/8/16,22/8/16,23/8/16,24/8/16,25/8/16,26/8/16,27/8/16,28/8/16,29/8/16,30/8/16,31/8/16,1/9/16,2/9/16,3/9/16,4/9/16,5/9/16,6/9/16,7/9/16,8/9/16,9/9/16,10/9/16,11/9/16,12/9/16,13/9/16,14/9/16,15/9/16,16/9/16,17/9/16,18/9/16,19/9/16,20/9/16,21/9/16,22/9/16,23/9/16,24/9/16,25/9/16,26/9/16,27/9/16,28/9/16,29/9/16,30/9/16,1/10/16,2/10/16,3/10/16,4/10/16,5/10/16,6/10/16,7/10/16,8/10/16,2/10/16,3/10/16,4/10/16,5/10/16,6/10/16,7/10/16,8/10/16,09/10/2016,10/10/2016,11/10/2016,12/10/2016,13/10/2016,14/10/2016,15/10/2016,16/10/2016,17/10/2016,18/10/2016,19/10/2016,20/10/2016,21/10/2016,22/10/2016,23/10/2016,24/10/2016,25/10/2016,26/10/2016,27/10/2016,28/10/2016,29/10/2016,30/10/2016,31/10/2016,01/11/2016,02/11/2016,03/11/2016,04/11/2016,05/11/2016,06/11/2016,07/11/2016,08/11/2016,09/11/2016,10/11/2016,11/11/2016,12/11/2016,13/11/2016,14/11/2016,15/11/2016,16/11/2016,17/11/2016,18/11/2016,19/11/2016,20/11/2016,21/11/2016,22/11/2016,23/11/2016,24/11/2016,25/11/2016,26/11/2016,27/11/2016,28/11/2016,29/11/2016,30/11/2016,01/12/2016,02/12/2016,03/12/2016,04/12/2016,05/12/2016,06/12/2016,07/12/2016,08/12/2016,09/12/2016,10/12/2016,11/12/2016,12/12/2016,13/12/2016,14/12/2016,15/12/2016,16/12/2016,17/12/2016,18/12/2016,19/12/2016,20/12/2016,21/12/2016,22/12/2016,23/12/2016,24/12/2016,25/12/2016,26/12/2016,27/12/2016,28/12/2016,29/12/2016,30/12/2016,31/12/2016,01/01/2017,02/01/2017,03/01/2017,04/01/2017,05/01/2017,06/01/2017,07/01/2017,08/01/2017,09/01/2017,10/01/2017,11/01/2017,12/01/2017,13/01/2017,14/01/2017,15/01/2017,16/01/2017,17/01/2017,18/01/2017,19/01/2017,20/01/2017,21/01/2017,22/01/2017,23/01/2017,24/01/2017,25/01/2017,26/01/2017,27/01/2017,28/01/2017,29/01/2017,30/01/2017,31/01/2017,01/02/2017,02/02/2017,03/02/2017,04/02/2017,05/02/2017,06/02/2017,07/02/2017,08/02/2017,09/02/2017,10/02/2017,11/02/2017,12/02/2017,13/02/2017,14/02/2017,15/02/2017,16/02/2017,17/02/2017,18/02/2017,19/02/2017,20/02/2017,21/02/2017,22/02/2017,23/02/2017,24/02/2017,25/02/2017,26/02/2017,27/02/2017,28/02/2017,01/03/2017,02/03/2017,03/03/2017,04/03/2017,05/03/2017,06/03/2017,07/03/2017,08/03/2017,09/03/2017,10/03/2017,11/03/2017,12/03/2017,13/03/2017,14/03/2017,15/03/2017,16/03/2017,17/03/2017,18/03/2017,19/03/2017,20/03/2017,21/03/2017,22/03/2017,23/03/2017,24/03/2017,25/03/2017,26/03/2017,27/03/2017,28/03/2017,29/03/2017,30/03/2017,31/03/2017,01/04/2017
Function,Stock Type,Process,Unit,Shift,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Inbound,Boxed,Total Boxed Inbound,Singles,Nights,28753,40776,40776,40776,40776,40776,28753,30776,54628,27699,54628,54628,54628,30776,33886,48057,48057,48057,48057,48057,33886,34232,48547,48547,48547,48547,48547,34232,31036,44014,44014,44014,44014,44014,31036,27777,39394,39394,39394,39394,39394,27777,28758,51046,25883,51046,51046,51046,28758,29189,41396,41396,41396,41396,41396,29189,26718,46756,46756,26718,46756,46756,26718,44613,63270,63270,63270,63270,63270,44613,39952,56660,56660,56660,56660,56660,39952,42442.17878,60190.72627,60190.72627,60190.72627,60190.72627,60190.72627,42442.17878,36979.88005,52444.19353,52444.19353,52444.19353,52444.19353,52444.19353,36979.88005,40308.06908,57164.17069,57164.17069,57164.17069,57164.17069,57164.17069,40308.06908,46676.58717,66195.88726,66195.88726,66195.88726,66195.88726,66195.88726,46676.58717,39409.75945,55890.20431,55890.20431,55890.20431,55890.20431,55890.20431,39409.75945,43296.5707,61402.40936,61402.40936,61402.40936,61402.40936,61402.40936,43296.5707,42459.3679,60215.10356,60215.10356,60215.10356,60215.10356,60215.10356,42459.3679,46535.68254,65996.05887,65996.05887,65996.05887,65996.05887,65996.05887,46535.68254,39267.83205,55688.92545,55688.92545,55688.92545,55688.92545,55688.92545,39267.83205,35169.72953,49877.07097,49877.07097,49877.07097,49877.07097,49877.07097,35169.72953,28787.26072,40825.56974,40825.56974,40825.56974,40825.56974,40825.56974,28787.26072,0,34683.57367,32858.12242,27381.76869,23730.86619,36509.02491,27381.76869,7889.088977,29978.53811,28400.72032,23667.26693,20511.63134,31556.35591,15778.17795,34548.03526,48995.39545,48995.39545,48995.39545,48995.39545,48995.39545,34548.03526,29586.82654,41959.49946,41959.49946,41959.49946,41959.49946,41959.49946,29586.82654,29142.11368,41328.81577,41328.81577,41328.81577,41328.81577,41328.81577,29142.11368,24446.63191,34669.7689,34669.7689,34669.7689,34669.7689,34669.7689,24446.63191,21871.48748,31017.74588,17894.85339,31813.07269,35789.70678,31017.74588,21871.48748,25878.56489,36700.51021,36700.51021,36700.51021,36700.51021,36700.51021,25878.56489,34473.60269,48889.83655,48889.83655,48889.83655,48889.83655,48889.83655,34473.60269,25470.73167,36122.12855,36122.12855,36122.12855,36122.12855,36122.12855,25470.73167,18392.09341,26083.33247,26083.33247,26083.33247,26083.33247,26083.33247,18392.09341,17921.55403,25416.02208,25416.02208,25416.02208,25416.02208,25416.02208,17921.55403,28883.3673,40961.86635,40961.86635,40961.86635,40961.86635,40961.86635,28883.3673,24868.17244,35267.59001,35267.59001,35267.59001,35267.59001,35267.59001,24868.17244
,,Total Boxed Inbound,Singles,AM,28753,40776,40776,40776,40776,40776,28753,30776,54628,27699,54628,54628,54628,30776,33886,48057,48057,48057,48057,48057,33886,34232,48547,48547,48547,48547,48547,34232,31036,44014,44014,44014,44014,44014,31036,27777,39394,39394,39394,39394,39394,27777,28758,51046,25883,51046,51046,51046,28758,29189,41396,41396,41396,41396,41396,29189,26718,46756,46756,26718,46756,46756,26718,44613,63270,63270,63270,63270,63270,44613,39952,56660,56660,56660,56660,56660,39952,42442.17878,60190.72627,60190.72627,60190.72627,60190.72627,60190.72627,42442.17878,36979.88005,52444.19353,52444.19353,52444.19353,52444.19353,52444.19353,36979.88005,40308.06908,57164.17069,57164.17069,57164.17069,57164.17069,57164.17069,40308.06908,46676.58717,66195.88726,66195.88726,66195.88726,66195.88726,66195.88726,46676.58717,39409.75945,55890.20431,55890.20431,55890.20431,55890.20431,55890.20431,39409.75945,43296.5707,61402.40936,61402.40936,61402.40936,61402.40936,61402.40936,43296.5707,42459.3679,60215.10356,60215.10356,60215.10356,60215.10356,60215.10356,42459.3679,46535.68254,65996.05887,65996.05887,65996.05887,65996.05887,65996.05887,46535.68254,39267.83205,55688.92545,55688.92545,55688.92545,55688.92545,55688.92545,39267.83205,35169.72953,49877.07097,49877.07097,49877.07097,49877.07097,49877.07097,35169.72953,28787.26072,40825.56974,40825.56974,40825.56974,40825.56974,40825.56974,28787.26072,0,34683.57367,32858.12242,27381.76869,23730.86619,36509.02491,27381.76869,7889.088977,29978.53811,28400.72032,23667.26693,20511.63134,31556.35591,15778.17795,34548.03526,48995.39545,48995.39545,48995.39545,48995.39545,48995.39545,34548.03526,29586.82654,41959.49946,41959.49946,41959.49946,41959.49946,41959.49946,29586.82654,29142.11368,41328.81577,41328.81577,41328.81577,41328.81577,41328.81577,29142.11368,24446.63191,34669.7689,34669.7689,34669.7689,34669.7689,34669.7689,24446.63191,21871.48748,31017.74588,17894.85339,31813.07269,35789.70678,31017.74588,21871.48748,25878.56489,36700.51021,36700.51021,36700.51021,36700.51021,36700.51021,25878.56489,34473.60269,48889.83655,48889.83655,48889.83655,48889.83655,48889.83655,34473.60269,25470.73167,36122.12855,36122.12855,36122.12855,36122.12855,36122.12855,25470.73167,18392.09341,26083.33247,26083.33247,26083.33247,26083.33247,26083.33247,18392.09341,17921.55403,25416.02208,25416.02208,25416.02208,25416.02208,25416.02208,17921.55403,28883.3673,40961.86635,40961.86635,40961.86635,40961.86635,40961.86635,28883.3673,24868.17244,35267.59001,35267.59001,35267.59001,35267.59001,35267.59001,24868.17244
```

Input after the following section of code:

```
...
if ($. < 4 ) {print ""}
elsif ($. > 8) {print ""}
elsif ($_ =~ /^\,\,\,\,/) {print substr($_,4)} #Tidy up excess white space
...
```

This outputs the following:

```
Site Activity,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,03:00 - 09:00 - Level 0 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,03:00 - 09:00 - Level 1 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.5 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,0,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,0,0,0,0,0,MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,Bank Hol,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.6 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,WCS/WMS Release 16.7 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Promotional Activity,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Sparks Preview to Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale & Cyber,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Home Event & Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,England vs Slovakia,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,0,0,0,0,0,Sparks Preview to Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,England vs Malta,0,0,0,0,0,0,England vs Malta,0,0,England vs Scotland,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,Home Event,0,Cyber,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F & Beauty Advent Calendar Launch (TBC),F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,Black Friday,0,0,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,Gifting Weekend,0,0,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,Xmas Countdown,0,0,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,Wrap Up,0,0,0,0,0,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,Sale,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Cyber,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,F&F,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Mothers Day    England vs Lithuania,0,0,0,0,0,0
Fiscal week,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52
Week,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
Date,31/7/16,1/8/16,2/8/16,3/8/16,4/8/16,5/8/16,6/8/16,7/8/16,8/8/16,9/8/16,10/8/16,11/8/16,12/8/16,13/8/16,14/8/16,15/8/16,16/8/16,17/8/16,18/8/16,19/8/16,20/8/16,21/8/16,22/8/16,23/8/16,24/8/16,25/8/16,26/8/16,27/8/16,28/8/16,29/8/16,30/8/16,31/8/16,1/9/16,2/9/16,3/9/16,4/9/16,5/9/16,6/9/16,7/9/16,8/9/16,9/9/16,10/9/16,11/9/16,12/9/16,13/9/16,14/9/16,15/9/16,16/9/16,17/9/16,18/9/16,19/9/16,20/9/16,21/9/16,22/9/16,23/9/16,24/9/16,25/9/16,26/9/16,27/9/16,28/9/16,29/9/16,30/9/16,1/10/16,2/10/16,3/10/16,4/10/16,5/10/16,6/10/16,7/10/16,8/10/16,2/10/16,3/10/16,4/10/16,5/10/16,6/10/16,7/10/16,8/10/16,09/10/2016,10/10/2016,11/10/2016,12/10/2016,13/10/2016,14/10/2016,15/10/2016,16/10/2016,17/10/2016,18/10/2016,19/10/2016,20/10/2016,21/10/2016,22/10/2016,23/10/2016,24/10/2016,25/10/2016,26/10/2016,27/10/2016,28/10/2016,29/10/2016,30/10/2016,31/10/2016,01/11/2016,02/11/2016,03/11/2016,04/11/2016,05/11/2016,06/11/2016,07/11/2016,08/11/2016,09/11/2016,10/11/2016,11/11/2016,12/11/2016,13/11/2016,14/11/2016,15/11/2016,16/11/2016,17/11/2016,18/11/2016,19/11/2016,20/11/2016,21/11/2016,22/11/2016,23/11/2016,24/11/2016,25/11/2016,26/11/2016,27/11/2016,28/11/2016,29/11/2016,30/11/2016,01/12/2016,02/12/2016,03/12/2016,04/12/2016,05/12/2016,06/12/2016,07/12/2016,08/12/2016,09/12/2016,10/12/2016,11/12/2016,12/12/2016,13/12/2016,14/12/2016,15/12/2016,16/12/2016,17/12/2016,18/12/2016,19/12/2016,20/12/2016,21/12/2016,22/12/2016,23/12/2016,24/12/2016,25/12/2016,26/12/2016,27/12/2016,28/12/2016,29/12/2016,30/12/2016,31/12/2016,01/01/2017,02/01/2017,03/01/2017,04/01/2017,05/01/2017,06/01/2017,07/01/2017,08/01/2017,09/01/2017,10/01/2017,11/01/2017,12/01/2017,13/01/2017,14/01/2017,15/01/2017,16/01/2017,17/01/2017,18/01/2017,19/01/2017,20/01/2017,21/01/2017,22/01/2017,23/01/2017,24/01/2017,25/01/2017,26/01/2017,27/01/2017,28/01/2017,29/01/2017,30/01/2017,31/01/2017,01/02/2017,02/02/2017,03/02/2017,04/02/2017,05/02/2017,06/02/2017,07/02/2017,08/02/2017,09/02/2017,10/02/2017,11/02/2017,12/02/2017,13/02/2017,14/02/2017,15/02/2017,16/02/2017,17/02/2017,18/02/2017,19/02/2017,20/02/2017,21/02/2017,22/02/2017,23/02/2017,24/02/2017,25/02/2017,26/02/2017,27/02/2017,28/02/2017,01/03/2017,02/03/2017,03/03/2017,04/03/2017,05/03/2017,06/03/2017,07/03/2017,08/03/2017,09/03/2017,10/03/2017,11/03/2017,12/03/2017,13/03/2017,14/03/2017,15/03/2017,16/03/2017,17/03/2017,18/03/2017,19/03/2017,20/03/2017,21/03/2017,22/03/2017,23/03/2017,24/03/2017,25/03/2017,26/03/2017,27/03/2017,28/03/2017,29/03/2017,30/03/2017,31/03/2017,01/04/2017
```

Comment: What do you mean by "except for the entire input CSV"?

Comment: what is the desired output? are you just trying to extract certain lines from a csv?

Comment: What was wrong with [Borodin's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38682489/176646) to your previous question?

Comment: I have looked at that solution and I had the discussion with him that this is using the hardcoded input that is in the `__DATA__` filehandler. I have tried to modify his answer to use my input filehandler `FILE` but to no avail. When I asked him, in the comments which have since been deleted, how to accomplish this he became quite hostile.

Comment: @choroba I mean the `CSV` is 300+ rows long and i am only after rows 5 - 7

Comment: Could you please supply a link to an example input file?

Comment: @beasy Please see the edited question for the desired output.

Comment: @DanWalmsley Please see the edited section of the question and I will put both inputs in there, the full `CSV` (ar and extract of it) and the desired input rows. (Rows 5 - 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @rows = ();
my @pivot = ();

open (FILE, "test.csv") or die $!; #Opens File or returns error thrown ($!) 

while (<FILE>) {
    if ($. < 4 ) {
        #next will just go to the next line of the csv
        next;
    }
    elsif ($. > 8) {
        #last will mean you jump out of the while loop and stop reading the csv
        last;
    }
    #So the regex is a little more complex the brackets are capture groups basically what is in side them will get put in $1, $2 and so on. 
    elsif ($_ =~ /^\,\,\,\,(.*?)\,(.*)/) {
        #in the first group is the header you want
        # the .* matches every thing, the ? Makes it non greedy (so you will stop with you see the next , 
        # then there is the funny $. == 8 ? I'm checking if your on line 8 , if you are you get the code in the first () else you get the second()
        # it's called the turnary operator. I want to avoid adding the last comma if we're on the last line
        $. == 8 ? (print "$1") : (print "$1, ");
        # now instead of in an else clause you want to grab the rest of the line here. 
        # what was happening before is you were ignoring the rest of the line and only getting into the else when nothing else matched
        # the $2 contains the rest of the line so basically doing what you were doing before but with $2
        chomp $2;
        push @rows, [split /,/, $2];
    }
}
#This is just to separate the header line
print "\n";

for my $row (@rows) {
    for my $column (0 .. $#{$row}) {
    push(@{$pivot[$column]}, $row->[$column]);
    }
}

for my $newrow (@pivot) {
    for my $newcol (@{$newrow}) {
    print $newcol,",";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close FILE or die $!;
```

You were close, the main issue was that you were thinking you were dealing with rest of the line in your else block. But you were actually on the lines that were the ones you wanted to throw away

EDIT

I'm getting the following output

```
Site Activity, Promotional Activity, Fiscal week, Week, Date
MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,18,31,31/7/16,
03:00 - 09:00 - Level 0 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,0,18,31,1/8/16,
03:00 - 09:00 - Level 1 Diverter Installation - SCS Loop,0,18,31,2/8/16,
0,0,18,31,3/8/16,
0,0,18,31,4/8/16,
0,0,18,31,5/8/16,
0,0,18,31,6/8/16,
MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,19,32,7/8/16,
0,0,19,32,8/8/16,
WCS/WMS Release 16.5 - Outage 03:00 - 11:00,0,19,32,9/8/16,
0,0,19,32,10/8/16,
0,0,19,32,11/8/16,
0,0,19,32,12/8/16,
0,0,19,32,13/8/16,
MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,0,20,33,14/8/16,
0,Sparks Preview to Sale,20,33,15/8/16,
0,Sale,20,33,16/8/16,
0,Sale,20,33,17/8/16,
0,Sale,20,33,18/8/16,
0,Sale,20,33,19/8/16,
0,Sale,20,33,20/8/16,
MI Report Outage 14:30 - 15:30,Sale,21,34,21/8/16,
```

Comment: so this is outputting the format I am after but it is missing the rest of the columns (2+) on each of the rows. so it is returning the following: Site Activity, Promotional Activity, Fiscal week, Week, Date but nothing else.

Comment: So you are not getting the same out put in the latest edit? Or is that not the output you are after?

Comment: so the output in your last edit is what I'm after but not what I am getting.

Comment: I have only added a `close FILE or die $!;` line to the very end of the file but even if I comment this out I still get the same.

Comment: Okay that is strange, it may be a Perl version issue or a range of other things. Just to rule out anything silly would you mind trying this https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pt5tg6ocpfrptt9/AADXHGp50VNJ3ThVc6NQRcv7a?dl=0

I've shared my version of the script and input file. If there are differences there it may explain the problem.

Comment: hmmm that seems to output perfectly

Comment: Ahhh got it in the test.pl you have the 2 for loops at the end. I removed them from mine. I have put these back in and it works perfectly. thank you:)

Comment: just realised there was a scroll bar -.- what you get for working on something at midnight.